# What can I do to fix a sink trap that's too low?

Tags: plumbing, sink

So I installed a new undermount deeper sink that messed up my plumbing. I had to cut/cap one of the wall drain to make room for the garbage disposal. So now I only have one drain to work with.
I reversed the p-trap wall tube to make up for the shortage. Is what I have acceptable? Anyone with better ideas? I am trying not to open the drywall behind but if that's the only way I am up for it :)

[image]

[image: double Y drain]

[image: dw2]

Comment: That's not the duplicate I intended. The subject is [widely covered already](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+sink+trap+lower+than+drain&rlz=1), though. I'll find a better one.

Comment: There's no problem draining two sinks through one trap. In fact, that's probably a more common arrangement. However, it looks from the first photo that your disposal's trap arm is lower than the drain outlet. Is that the case, or is it parallax error in the photo?

Comment: unfortunately it is the case "disposal's trap arm is lower than the drain outlet." As matter of fact even with Jbend I wont be able to reach the wall tube :(

Comment: Do you really *need* a garbage disposal?

Comment: I'm thinking of just dropping it. I opened the back wall the drain line is horizontal and there are two copper water lines that are running right underneath. It sucks how what supposed to be small quickie job turned to big monster.

Answer (score 4):

The trap is too low, and the only solution (in this case where we can see that the drain from the disposal is below the wall entry) to that other than a sink that doesn't cause that is opening the wall and making a lower entry into the drain pipe (you can save the current entry as a clean-out.)

In some cases (not this one) trimming the tailpieces shorter will do, but unless you lose the disposal (the other solution to get the trap up several inches) that won't save you here.

You should also correct the wonky angle on the non-disposal sink tee, which will probably leak.

When you finish the plumbing, fix the drywall. Gaps around pipes like that are very popular with rodents and other pests.